# PouchDB with LocalStorage

Tags: local-storage, pouchdb

I try use PouchDB  version 6.4.3 with pouchdb-adapter-localstorage version 6.4.2, but I have exception:

> 2019-01-04 20:29:29,764 [ERROR] Message: PouchDB.
>   ExceptionMessage:.status required, old abstract-leveldown, line:8,
>   source:file:///opt/usr/apps/j7gZyYA2wq/res/wgt/core/lib/pouchdb.localstorage.min.js,
>   name:AssertionError

What does it mean?

I found an answer on [PouchDB](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6949) but can't understand the post. Please explain how to work with local storage adapter in new versions PouchDB?

Comment: Are you using it in the browser, in NodeJs or some other environment?

Comment: I use it in browser

Comment: If that is the case, then the file storage location: ```file:///opt/usr/apps/j7gZyYA2wq/res/wgt/core/lib/pouchdb.localstorage.min.js``` is VERY unusual.  ```/opt``` is a directory for the user's optional stuff, the browser should have no access. ```/opt/usr/``` is even weirder.  I use Linux exclusively and PouchDB a lot. My ```/opt``` directories have nothing like that.  I suggest you get some bare bones PouchDB demo code, get that working, and build up from there.

Comment: I would also like to know why you are concerned about LocalStorage.  A key benefit of PouchDb is to be able to ignore what storage any particular browser offers; it'll find a way to work properly in 99.99% of the browsers out there.